# Return AWS signature over HTTP

Tags: javascript, security, amazon-s3

I am performing multipart upload to S3 straight from the browser, i.e. bypassing my back-end.

My JS code sends a hand-shake request to S3 (a POST), then uploads the file in chunks of 5MB  (a PUT for each) and eventually, finalises the file (a POST).

That works well. As you can guess, each request to S3 (hand-shake, part uploads and finalisation) has to be signed. It is of course out of the question to generate the signature in JS as it would expose my AWS secret key.

What I am doing so far is the following : before each request to S3, I send a request to my own back-end (to `/sign?method=HTTPMethod&path=URLToSign`) which returns the signature string. This way, all AWS credentials stay in the back-end, as should be.

My question is the following : **Is this secure?**

Answer (score 0):

One thing you should take into account is that anyone that sees the address you are calling to get the signature string could abuse it to upload any file (and any number of files) on behalf of you/your application.

To avoid that, my first guess would be to implement some sort of validation in the back-end, so for example, you wouldn't sign URLs if you were getting more than X requests per second.

Also, if you need to filter some files out (exe's, huge files that could rise your AWS bill) I don't think bypassing your back-end is a good idea because you have no control over which files are getting uploaded (maybe your user uploads a file named `kitten.png` which is actually a 700 mb iso file)

Comment: Excellent point, I'm stupid for not thinking of it. What I could also do is filter the referrer of the request. The request should come from my own domain. About bypassing the back-end, I kinda have to since Heroku has a very short timeout on requests so that large file upload are out of the question.

Comment: @EmmanuelTurlay It all depends on how much you trust your users (intranet corporate users, the whole internet?) and how many efforts you can put in (i) development and (ii) maintenance/surveillance . Checking for the referer would filter out light attacks like those made by "script kiddies" but a serious attack could involve spoofing of the referer, as this field is sent by the client side. You could also ask at security.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I could also make sure the request is an XHR. Cross-domain XHR are forbidden by browsers and curl style queries would fail the XHR requirement.